# In Slack, is it possible to create editable posts from a bot?

Tags: slack, slack-commands

I want to create a bot to simplify some reporting. I have already implemented a post service to do the formatting we want, but the message is not editable by the person who typed the / command.

My question: is it possible for the bot to post as 'me' so that I can edit the message after it's created? Some older documentation implies it can, but with the app manifest, the documentation isn't exactly clear.

If it's possible, can somebody point me to a good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for the bot to post as you.

**What you need :**

1.Create a user token for the user who wants to post.

2. Store this token where bot can access the token.

3. When posting, the bot will use this token so that it seems that the user has posted the content.

As the post will be done by user, that user can edit the post.

Comment: this helped me find his link: https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2#using